# Setting SyndicationItem Categories property

Tags: c#, syndication-item

I'm working with the `SyndicationItem` class and have found the `Categories` property.

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem.categories(v=vs.110).aspx) this property doesn't have a setter, I have however found out that I can write to the property, i.e.

```
var syndicationItem = new SyndicationItem
{
    Categories = { new SyndicationCategory("Category name") }
};
```

Now, that's not good enough since I can't enumerate my values like that. If I do something like this

```
var categoryCollection = new Collection<SyndicationCategory>();

var syndicationItem = new SyndicationItem
{
    Categories = categoryCollection
};
```

The `Categories` property get all squiggled up and tells me there's no setter.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation and the compiler are right - the `Categories` property doesn't have a setter.

The first example you posted does not assign a new value to the `Categories` property. It gets the existing value and calls the Add method to add each `SyndicationCategory` you specify in the initializer.

You will have to add categories to the existing collection:

```
var syndicationItem = new SyndicationItem();
Collection<SyndicationCategory> categoryCollection = GetCategories();
foreach (var category in categoryCollection)
{
    syndicationItem.Categories.Add(category);
}
```